# F#: Type inference not finding the correct overload

Tags: f#, type-inference

I've written a function and I have started to refactor it, but I'm having some problems with a  "A unique overload for method 'Round' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point." error, but I don't understand why.

```
let CheckValuesLin (lowValue, highValue) multiplier (sigFigs:int) =
    let arithmean (lowValue, highValue) =
        (lowValue + highValue) / 2.0
    let createRangeValue numberModifier meanfunction= 
        let mean = meanfunction (lowValue, highValue)
        let rangeValue = mean + (numberModifier mean) * multiplier
        Math.Round(rangeValue, sigFigs)
    let createRangeValues valueCreatingFunction=
        (createRangeValue makeNegative arithmean, createRangeValue keepPositive arithmean)
    let greatestMinValue, lowestMaxValue = createRangeValues createRangeValue
    (greatestMinValue, lowestMaxValue)
```

The line that fails is the Math.Round line, which vanishes when I set `range` to `range: float`. This confuses me, as everything I hover over seems to have the correct type inferred already, including range and mean.

I don't mind putting the type hinting in, I would just like to know why it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that F# type inference is strictly left to right, top to bottom.

In the `createRangeValue` function, the compiler can only infer that all the values are numeric, there is nothing to force the types to be `float`.

Whilst the call to `arithmean` later on would seem to give some of the values float types, this occurs after the call to `Round`, so the compiler cannot infer types.

**EDIT** Some more detail:
Essentially the compiler sees this:

```
let lowValue = 0.0 //I am being genrous by making this have a type
let highValue = 0.0
let sigFigs = 0 //this type is known
let createRangeValue (numberModifier) (meanfunction) multiplier= 
    let mean = meanfunction (lowValue, highValue)    
    let rangeValue = mean + (numberModifier mean) * multiplier
    Math.Round(rangeValue, sigFigs)
```

In this case, `rangeValue` could be either `float` or `Decimal` as both would satisfy all the constraints present.

For me, this works fine

```
open System
let makeNegative a = -a
let keepPositive a = a
let CheckValuesLin (lowValue, highValue) multiplier (sigFigs:int) =
    let arithmean (lowValue, highValue) =
        (lowValue + highValue) / 2.0
    let createRangeValue numberModifier (meanfunction: float * float -> float)= 
        let mean = meanfunction (lowValue, highValue)
        let rangeValue = mean + (numberModifier mean) * multiplier
        Math.Round(rangeValue, sigFigs)
    let createRangeValues valueCreatingFunction=
        (createRangeValue makeNegative arithmean, createRangeValue keepPositive arithmean)
    let greatestMinValue, lowestMaxValue = createRangeValues createRangeValue
    (greatestMinValue, lowestMaxValue)
```

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't a type hint on "meanFunction" of type float*float->float fix the problem? It doesn't, so maybe I've misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @Sean - there is still an undertimed type in `numberModifier` - although I think it should be infered to be `float -> float` this is not done for some reason.  Adding this type annotation fixes the problem, though I am not sure why

Comment: @Sean - I initially got the same error as you, but resetting my fsi made it go away, I added code with an annotation only on `meanfunction` that works for me